# In (hyperledger fabric)kafka ordering service which orderer node will be signing and broadcasting the block to all the anchor peers

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric

While configuring kafka ordering service, all the ordering nodes will be having the same blocks of transactions. As each orderer signature is different from each other, who will be signing and sending a particular block to all peers at the time of commit? Is there any criteria or priority order in which peers or anchor peers will select a particular orderer node, and all peers will agree on that criteria? If suppose where we will be specifying that criteria?(suppose if there are 3 orderer nodes)

Comment: a small off topic note:Its not necessary the block would be sent to the anchor peer,technically the blocks are sent to leader peer.leader peer can be static(hard coded)or dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the ordering service, you specify the membership information (aka orderer org MSP) for the ordering organization(s) in the initial genesis block.  This information is then included in the channel config for every channel and propagated to peers when they join channels.  So peers will verify block signatures from any orderer node whose certificate was issued by the orderer MSP, which means it does not matter from which ordering node the peer receives blocks.

Comment: hey @Gari just a small doubt,so its not necessary all the peers would receive the block from only one orderer? All the peers can get the block from different orderers?

Comment: hi @Gari If every orderer node is cutting block the which will be broadcasted in network??(block with which orderer signature will be taken?).In that case what if all the peers having same block data with different orderer signature?Can you please explain in detail what happens internally?

Comment: hey @rishabh sharma Actually while testing kafka ordering service locally with the use of commithandler.js file when i read block information i could find only one orderer signature(unless it is down) even though 3 orderer nodes were active also if one orderer is down which orderer will be creating the coming blocks?@Gari Do different peers will commit different signature block or all are fetching from only one orderer? Could you please explain in detail what is happening? Kindly help on the same.

Comment: Kafka is used as a replication mechanism across the ordering nodes.  There is logic inside the orderer nodes to ensure that all nodes cut the same blocks.  The peer itself will generally only connect to a single ordering node (unless one goes down in which case it will connect to the next one in the list).

Comment: hey @GariSingh yaaa..But how will peers will decide to which orderer it should connect and how will all the peers will end up in same orderer??

Comment: We've made some changes, but the peers randomly pick from the list of orderers in the config block for the channel.  It does not actually matter to which orderer node each peer connects.

Comment: But for each orderer nodes the signature will be different know? so the committed block on each peer's ledger will differ from each other know??I am really confused. Kindly help on the same

Comment: @GariSingh Could you please explain from where we can find the random algorithm of picking up orderers??

Comment: I think you are going a bit overboard here; I'm not quite sure what the concern is?

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/v1.4.1/core/comm/producer.go#L71

Comment: @GariSingh Yaaa..Actually i wanted to know the how the orderer is picked up.(I just wanted to ensure whether we can decide the order of orderer selection or not). Thank you.. I think this link will help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,
here is the [link](https://codeburst.io/the-abcs-of-kafka-in-hyperledger-fabric-81e6dc18da56) which would explain the entire ordering process.

All in all Kafka is just helping the orderers to be in sync with each other and have blocks set in a perfect order.
So inshort the Answer for your question is orderer which is connected to the delivery client would sign the transaction.

Comment: hey@RisabhSharma Sorry. I didnt get it completely. Could you please explain in detail, If there are 3 orderer nodes(ordere0 order1 and ordere2) and which will connected to peers while broadcasting one block and if it is down among 3 in which order(orderer 1 or orderer2 ,suppose orderer0 was down) the next orderer will be broadcasting blocks??

Comment: The orderers in kafka based oderering service follow leader-follower system.wherein the leader owns a partition, and the follower has a replication of the same. When the leader dies, the follower becomes the new leader.(Orderer 0 is the leader in your case suppose the orderer 0 is down then the kafka cluster would decide which orderer would be the leader)Please go through this answer to understand the working of kafka.please go through this question,iam sure this would clear everything.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024609/what-happens-if-a-kafka-consumer-instance-dies

Comment: But orderer nodes and kafka nodes are different from each other know?? kafka nodes will be handled by zookeeper and in my understanding  leader follower system is inside kafka clusters and from there orderer nodes are taking transactions. So whenever timeout happens kafka will ask to cut the block and all orderers will be cutting the block and keeping in its own local ledger. But delivery of blocks will be done only by one orderer. I would like to know which orderer will be that? are we specifying any orderer criteria for that in yaml files? or in our node sdk??

Comment: or are we specifying anything inside kafka configurations which ordererit should take first? and while testing i could see unless one orderer goes down it is only following that orderer for the rest of the transactions.

Comment: Kafka itself decides who would become the leader. Orderers receive and send blocks to kafka so that it can maintain its records.so when one orderer is down other would be signing the block.when when its up it would start pulling the lost data and continue its task like other orderers.

Comment: If three orderers are there and one orderer went down.. so among other two orderers who will be signing the next block(orderer1 or orderer2)? will that be decided by kafka? if so may i know based on what algorithm kafka is taking this decision?